# Improve diff viewer in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, diff

In Visual Studio 2010 you can compare a local file with the latest version/workspace version. This opens up a diff viewer showing the two versions of the file side by side with the lines that are changed or added highlighted.

Is there a way to improve this diff viewer to show (with e.g. a darker background color) which part of the line exactly was changed (like for example on github).

This would be especially useful if for example a typo was corrected in a long line of text. Now I have to squint for a long time at the two lines before I spot the difference, just having the letter that was changed highlighted would help me tremendously.

Comment: You can use [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/). Just a suggestion.

Comment: @AlvinWong Thanks, I didn't know you could do that, exactly what I was looking for! [This link](http://blog.paulbouwer.com/2010/01/31/replace-diffmerge-tool-in-visual-studio-team-system-with-winmerge) gives step-by-step instructions. Add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: You could extend this behavior through an Visual Studio extension.